# How to get dynamic created table's total column and row using Request.Form in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, model-view-controller, controller, row

I am doing my project in Vb.net using MVC 4.0

I have created dynamic table and in that textboxes in td using javascript and now i want to get that table's total row and column as well for further process in Controller function.

How I can get using above using VB.net?

I have used Request.Form but the id of the textboxes in table is created uniquely so first I want to find the total column and row so based on that I can move further and check using for loop.

Comment: What code have you written so far?

Comment: I have created table using javascript and i search google to get those table's total row and column in vb.net but i didn't get any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [Solved]

I got all the controls on code behind by it's name by using FormCollection just i need to do is post back the form using form action method because with using ajax i am not getting  the formcollection in code behind but directly using form action method i can get all the controls name.
[image]

These are the textbox ids by which i can get the value just need to do further process like:

```
For Each _formvalues As String In formcol
     formcol(_formvalues)
  Next
```

fomcol is an object of FormCollection,_formvalues is used for moving one by one name coming in formcol and to take the data inside means name just write formcol(_formvalues) that's it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like if you are generating your table through javascript you should also be able to set the value of a hidden field to the value you are outputting to your totals column. If you created a hidden field with the value set you should be able to access it from the Request collection. If it is not actually in a field that gets posted back you will only be able to access the value from the client-side.

```
document.getElementById("myInput").value = "Value you are outputting to your "total" cell
```

Comment: Yes DonnieDarko I got the total but i want the textboxes id which i have created inside the td in the tr of dynamic generated table so i can get the value from textboxes.  How can I get the td of tr from dynamic generated table?

Comment: If you name your textboxes properly, you should have no problem pulling the data from them in the server side via the Request collection.

Comment: Yes you are right DonnieDarko if you think my answer is correct so please don't hesitate to give my answer up and click right sign to accept this answer thanx a lot for helping.